# Python Tkinter pop-up not being displayed

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to get a Tkinter popup to display when a button is clicked.My issue is that every thing runs just fine except the popup will not produce. I have tried multiple ways to create the popup using *tkMessagebox* and *Toplevel()* but still not luck. The program runs but when the button is click nothing happens. I have referenced similar post but still can not find the issue in my code. Any thoughts?

```
from tkinter import *

def new():
    root2 = Tk()
    root2.geometry('250x250')
    l = Label(root2,text="Please Scan Tag").pack()
    root2.mainloop()

# setting main frame
root = Tk()
root.geometry('800x650')
root.title("Pass")
root.configure(background= "white")
label_0 = Label(root, text="Pass",width=10,font=("bold", 50),fg= "green",bg="white")
label_0.place(x=186,y=76)
Button(root,command="new", text='new',font= 
("bold",15),width=15,height=4,bg='blue',fg='white').place(x=155,y=300)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You have to pass an actual function to the button - `command=new` perhaps - rather than a string that's the name of a function.  And you really want to use `Toplevel()` for the popup, a second call to `Tk()` will cause all sorts of problems.

Comment: @jasonharper That was it, thanks! Had to change "new" to command= new .Also changed Tk() to Toplevel()

Answer (score 1):

The `command` option requires a reference to a callable function, not a string.

```
Button(root,command=new, ...)
```

Comment: Hi Bryan, while I appreciate your experience and practically learnt tkinter from your answers, I want to politely ask why you have posted as an answer the equivalent of the content of a comment which has already resolved the issue.

Comment: @MinionJim: it is because comments aren't answers. They can't be downvoted or accepted as the best answer, and they can't be searched. A comment won't be indexed by google the way an answer will be. A question without an accepted answer isn't very useful to others, and the primary goal of this site is to create a body of questions _and_ answers that are useful to many people.